# Which is the best/correct way to represent a value in a span/div tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say i need to keep track of a value (product price) in html, to use it in javascript. For example:

```
Product A: $<span>200.00</span>
Product B: $<span>300.00</span>
```

Not considering javascript here, but HTML, it's possible to describe the products and values in many ways, like:

```
<span>200</span>
<span value="200"></span>
<span data-value="200"></span>
<span title="200"></span>
```

etc...

What is the nicer and semantically correct way to represent the value of the product?

Comment: imo "data-value". "value" is a reserved attribute for inputs and stuff (as well as "title" is for images)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only two of those are really viable, and only one lets you represent the value separately from its appearance/representation:

These are viable:

```
<span>200</span>
<span data-value="200"></span>
```

And this is the only one that lets you represent the value separately from its representation:

```
<span data-value="200"></span>
```

But you'd want to *also* include a representation of it, e.g.:

```
<span data-value="200">$200</span>
```

Using a `value` on `span` would be invalid HTML, and using `title` would be using a UI feature to contain data.

Answer (score 2):

On the level of HTML, a price does not hold specific semantic meaning. Specifically in your first example it's not even a price, as you're leaving out the currency - it's just a number. Therefore a semanticless `<span>` is fine.

You appear to be looking for [microformats](http://microformats.org/) or microdata, specifically the [Product](http://schema.org/Product) schema. This allows you to provide extra markup for search engines and the like, for example:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="name">Kenmore White 17" Microwave</span>
  <img src="kenmore-microwave-17in.jpg" alt='Kenmore 17" Microwave' />
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating"
    itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
   Rated <span itemprop="ratingValue">3.5</span>/5
   based on <span itemprop="reviewCount">11</span> customer reviews
  </div>
  <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
    <!--price is 1000, a number, with locale-specific thousands separator
    and decimal mark, and the $ character is marked up with the
    machine-readable code "USD" -->
    <span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD">$</span><span
          itemprop="price" content="1000.00">1,000.00</span>
    <link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock" />In stock
  </div>
  Product description:
  <span itemprop="description">0.7 cubic feet countertop microwave.
  Has six preset cooking categories and convenience features like
  Add-A-Minute and Child Lock.</span>
  Customer reviews:
  <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <span itemprop="name">Not a happy camper</span> -
    by <span itemprop="author">Ellie</span>,
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-04-01">April 1, 2011
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1">
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">1</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
    </div>
    <span itemprop="description">The lamp burned out and now I have to replace
    it. </span>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="review" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Review">
    <span itemprop="name">Value purchase</span> -
    by <span itemprop="author">Lucas</span>,
    <meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2011-03-25">March 25, 2011
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating">
      <meta itemprop="worstRating" content = "1"/>
      <span itemprop="ratingValue">4</span>/
      <span itemprop="bestRating">5</span>stars
    </div>
    <span itemprop="description">Great microwave for the price. It is small and
    fits in my apartment.</span>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

This is the recommended way to introduce smart meaning to elements without W3C having to clutter up HTML standards with every tiny concept of semantic meaning.

[Schema.org itself was created](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1211158?hl=en) by the 'large search engine folks' specifically for this purpose:

> schema.org is a collaboration by Google, Microsoft, and Yahoo! to
>   improve the web by creating a structured data markup schema supported
>   by major search engines. On-page markup helps search engines
>   understand the information on webpages and provide richer results. A
>   shared markup vocabulary makes it easier for webmasters to decide on a
>   markup schema and get maximum benefit for their efforts.